# Can't get charts to vertically autofit screen, despite using height=100% or autofit

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

So i’m new to plotly, and can’t seem to find a fix for this issue. I have four charts that I want displayed in a column, at full screen, i.e., i want to see all four charts vertically, without having to scroll.

When i plot them, however, I end up having to scroll down. I have tried setting size=100% or autofit=True, but neither worked - the column in which the charts are displayed is still too big for the screen, and i need to scroll. However, when i used width=50%, that worked; the charts only take half the width of the screen, but i still need to scroll down to view them all. I have listed my code below.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    # State
    html.Div([
        html.H1(id='map-header',children='State'),
        dcc.Graph(id='map-graph',
                  figure={'data':[{'x':[3,2],'y':[7,12]}],'layout':{'title':'State'}}),
    # Business Units
    html.Div([
        html.H1(id='bu-header',children='Business Units'),
        dcc.Graph(id='bu-graph',
                  figure={'data':[{'x':[3,2],'y':[7,12]}],'layout':{'title':'Business Unit'}})
    ]),
    # Job Family
    html.Div([
        html.H1(id='jf-header',children='Job Family'),
        dcc.Graph(id='jf-graph',
                  figure={'data':[{'x':[3,2],'y':[7,12]}],'layout':{'title':'Job Family'}})
    ]),
    # Job Level
    html.Div([
        html.H1(id='fl-header',children='Job Level'),
        dcc.Graph(id='jl-graph',
                  figure={'data':[{'x':[3,2],'y':[7,12]}],'layout':{'title':'Job Level'}})
    ])
    ])

],style={'width':'50%'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of each graph to 100 by adding `'height':'100'` inside the `dcc.graph` part like so:

```
dcc.Graph(id='jl-graph',
              figure={'data':[{'x':[3,2],'y':[7,12]}],'layout':{'title':'Job Level', 'height':'100'}})
```

But do remember, that there is a possibility that the graph would not look readable this way. Alternately I suggest, that you use other `layout` components of dash, like `rows` and `columns`, or `cards`, and add your graph inside these components, then they resize to fit that `container` in which they are.

Comment: I'll try that, but I also want to be able to have these dashboard adjust to any screens, not just my own. Any ideas as to why, adding height:100% in the style dictionary of the first Div doesn't work?

Comment: Ah for that you need to use `main_page = dbc.Container([
      body
], fluid=True)` and then call it in your app as `app.layout = html.Div([
    lyt.main_page
])`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't worked with dbc before so i have some questions. by `[body]`, I'm assuming this is everything inside my first Div in layout, is that correct? Also, when you say `lyt.main_page`, what is `lyt`?

Comment: Ah sorry for not clarifying that. You are right about `body` - it is all that you have in your Div. And i usually put all my `layout` content in a separate file called `layout.py` and have that imported in `index.py` or in your case `app.py` as `import layout as lyt`. This way i can call specific html content in the page if segregated well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to format my code in the way you suggested, but the main container still does not fit my screen, and adds a scroll bar. See the image below: https://imgur.com/EvHSgm7
Any ideas as to why this keeps happening, i.e., dashboards not fitting to screen size?

Comment: There are two things here. The `fluid layout` is for maintaining the view auto adjusting to all screens. Then the next is size of the graph. So for that, either you change individual graphs height and width as suggested in my original answer, or use row column layout options to fit them all better. I suggest play around with `dash_bootstrap_components` and `dash html components`